# What is the relationship between Roles on the Authorize tag and IdentityServer3 client setup

Tags: c#, identityserver3

In the Authorize tag, if specify a Role, access is denied and I can't figure out how to configure IdentityServer3 to allow the Role.  I'm using the client credentials flow. Here is the tag:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Read")]
```

The code I've used to create the client is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetClientsToAddUpdate()
{
    return new Client[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientName = "Portal Client Name",
            Enabled = true,
            ClientId = "portalClientName",
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
            {
                new Secret("AVerySecretSecret".Sha256())
            },
            Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
            AllowClientCredentialsOnly = true,
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                "Read"
            },

            Claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("client_type", "headless"),
                new Claim("client_owner", "Portal"),
                new Claim("add_detail", "allow")
            },
            PrefixClientClaims = false
        }
    };
}
```

I have a Scope of Read and send that Scope when getting the Bearer Token and if I use an Authorize tag with no Roles specified everything works.  As soon as I add a Role authorization is denied.  **How do I modify the Client to add the "Read" Role?**

Some background is I'd like to use Swagger via Swashbuckle to give clients a sandbox to play with the API and I can't get the authorization to work, so I'd like to add Role since this seems to get the Swagger UI closer to working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this mapping ends up breaking the specific claim names defined as `name` and `role`, because their names get transformed and no longer map to what you were expecting.

This results in the `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` and `User.IsInRole("")` not working as expected.

[Please refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850498/using-asp-net-role-authorisation-with-identityserver3-implicit-flow/35871889#35871889) also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772193/identityserver3-requiring-a-role-when-the-user-logs-in-as-additional-credential?rq=1)